# Why are my tags not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been tearing my hair out over this! Inside of Unity, I am trying to make it so if the object the player collides with has a "Kill" tag, the player respawns. This is turning into a very hard task, because for no apparent reason this does not work:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
        audio.Play();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Kill"))
    {
        Respawn();
    }
}
```

It seems that if I use any other tag besides `"Pick Up"`, it will simply not detect it at all. I have even tried reversing the tags and adding them to different objects to no avail!

My `Respawn()` function is also working correctly. Adding this above the line doesn't send anything to the console:

```
 Debug.Log("Respawn");
 Respawn();
```

I am also certain I am checking for the right tag in the script, as I have copied and pasted it from the Unity Inspector window. Do you see anything wrong here?

[image: Inspector Window]

Also, here are the settings for the `RigidBody` inside of my obbject:
[image: RigidBody]

Everything looks like it should be working fine, but it doesn't. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logical error. Remove the else statement. With the else statement, if the first if statement is true, it won't check the next if statement.

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
{
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    count = count + 1;
    SetCountText();
    audio.Play();
}

if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Kill"))
{
    Respawn();
}
```

**EDIT**:

Make sure that your GameObject with the `Kill` tag has its `Is Trigger` property **checked**. Also make sure there is a `Rigidbody` attached to that GameObject.

Comment: Ok. How about you put  **only** `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Kill"))` in the `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` function, for now then put `Debug.Log("1")` outside the if statement then `Debug.Log("2")` inside the if statement

Comment: I only want to see  the log not if it works or not. What logs did you see after this modification?

Comment: "1" is sent to the log while "2" is not.

Comment: Ok. I am helping you troubleshoot your code. Now put `Debug.Log("Name: " + other.gameObject.name + "  Tag: " + other.gameObject.tag);` under `Debug.Log("1")` which is outside the if statement. Let me know what happens

Comment: Thank you for the help! That was a clever way to debug, but now, even though I have that written before the if statement, nothing will be shown in the log unless the object is tagged with "Pick Up"!

Comment: It simply means that GameObjects tagged with `Kill` are not being detected. Edit your question, select your that GameObject with the `Kill` tag and upload a picture of its collider and rigidbody settings. While you are at it, look at the Edit I made in my answer.

Comment: I updated that to my answer before you did. I realized that you are using `OnTriggerEnter` not `OnCollisonrEnter`.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120318/discussion-between-klink45-and-programmer).

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you understand a simple debugging with `Debug.Log`. That will be useful in the future if you know how to do that.

Comment: I have used that in the past in other languages, but it never crossed my mind to even do that for some reason.

Comment: That's what I use in Unity 70 percent of the time. Although, using real debugging is quicker, `Debug.Log` lets you see what's going on from the Editor instead of the IDE debugger. You should use it for things like this. There is also `Debug.DrawLine` if you don't know that. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just use an empty Script attached to the "Kill" Object and use TryGetComponent() to check.
Do like this:

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if (other.TryGetComponent<Kill>(out Kill kill)) {
        // What you want do
    }
}
```